# PHP registration form fails when optional input field is blank

Tags: php, forms

I am **NEW** to PHP/HTML/JAVASCRIPT and Stackoverflow etc. however, the only hurdle I have with my form is "a field that DOES NOT require data" (dependant on user input) is preventing successful submission. When I remove the "isset($post[number2]) etc. as example, it works very well! How do I include the necessary issets and accept blank entries to successfully submit my PHP form please? I hope I've explained this well? Sorry for the naming protocols, and thanks in advance. Code Below:

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    $email_subject = "Register Request";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.       ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['name2']) ||

        !isset($_POST['number']) ||

        !isset($_POST['number2']) ||

        !isset($_POST['alternate']) ||

        !isset($_POST['accnum']) ||

        !isset($_POST['accnam']) ||

        !isset($_POST['cardnum']) ||

        !isset($_POST['expdate']) ||

        !isset($_POST['service1']) ||

        !isset($_POST['service2']) ||

        !isset($_POST['service3']) ||

        !isset($_POST['licence']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email2']) ||

        !isset($_POST['phone']) 


        ) 
        {

       died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you   submitted.');       

    }



    $name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $name2 = $_POST['name2']; 

    $number = $_POST['number']; // required

    $number2 = $_POST['number2']; 

    $alternate = $_POST['alternate']; // required

    $accnum = $_POST['accnum']; 

    $accnam = $_POST['accnam']; 

    $cardnum = $_POST['cardnum']; 

    $expdate = $_POST['expdate']; 

    $service1 = $_POST['service1']; // required

    $service2 = $_POST['service2']; // required

    $service3 = $_POST['service3']; // required

    $licence = $_POST['licence']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $email_from2 = $_POST['email2']; 

    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required


    {
    $phone = array();
    foreach($_POST['phone'] as $val)
    {
    $phone[] = (string) $val;
    }
    $phone = implode(',', $phone);

    }

    $time = $_POST['time'];


    {
    $time = array();
    foreach($_POST['time'] as $val)
    {
    $time[] = (string) $val;
    }
    $time = implode(',', $time);

    }

    $SelectedDate = $_POST['SelectedDate'];



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z0-9 .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$number)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }


  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Register Request\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($number)."\n";   

    $email_message .= "Date of Birth: ".clean_string($alternate)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Licence/Passport: ".clean_string($licence)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Service No.1: ".clean_string($service1)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Service No.2: ".clean_string($service2)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Service No.3: ".clean_string($service3)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Payment Option: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "BSB Number: ".clean_string($name2)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Account Number: ".clean_string($accnum)."\n"; 

    $email_message .= "Account Name: ".clean_string($number2)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Account Name: ".clean_string($accnam)."\n";

    $email_message .= "C/C Name: ".clean_string($email_from2)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Card Number: ".clean_string($cardnum)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Expiry Date: ".clean_string($expdate)."\n";





    // create email headers

    $headers = 'From: '.$name."\r\n".

    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

     @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

     ?>



        <!-- include your own success html here -->



        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        top.location.href = "success.html";
        //-->
        </script>




Here is the HTML code...


<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                      <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
      <tr>
        <td width="15%">Your Full Name</td>
        <td width="1%">:</td>
        <td width="33%">
          <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50" required autofocus /></td>
        <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="14%">Date of Birth</td>
        <td width="1%">:</td>
        <td width="32%">
        <input name="alternate" type="date" id="alternate" size="20" required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Your Address</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="number" type="text" id="number" value="" size="50" maxlength="60" required/></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Licence/Passport No.</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="licence" type="number" id="licence" value="" size="15" maxlength="10" requried/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email Address</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="50" required/></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><strong>Service No.1</strong></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="service1" type="number" id="service1" value="" size="11" maxlength="10" required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><strong>Service No.2</strong></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="service2" type="number" id="service2" value="" size="11" maxlength="10" /></td>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><strong>Service No.3</strong></td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="service3" type="number" id="service3" value="" size="11" maxlength="10" /></td>
        </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>

  <tr>
    <td>Payment Options</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="phone[]" type="radio" value="no" id="phone_no"/><label for="checkbox">Credit Card</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="phone[]" value="yes" id="phone_yes"/><label for="checkbox">Direct Debit</label></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                                          <tr>
                                            <td width="15%">BSB No.</td>
                                            <td width="1%">:</td>
                                            <td width="32%"><input name="name2" type="text" id="name2" size="50" /></td>
                                            <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td width="13%">Account Number</td>
                                            <td width="1%">:</td>
                                            <td width="33%"><input name="accnum" type="number" id="accnum" size="20" /></td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>Account Name</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><input name="number2" type="text" id="number2" value="" size="50" maxlength="25" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>Account in Name of</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><input name="accnam" type="text" id="accnam" value="" size="50" maxlength="25" /></td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>Name on Credit Card</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><input name="email2" type="text" id="email2" size="50" /></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>Card No.</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><input name="cardnum" type="number" id="cardnum" value="" size="50" maxlength="20" /></td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>Expiry Date</td>
                                            <td>:</td>
                                            <td><input name="expdate" type="number" id="expdate" value="" size="11" maxlength="4" /></td>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>

                                          </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>


                                            <tr>
                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                              <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td><a class="btn" href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td><a class="btn" href="termscond.html">see our Terms & Conditions</a></td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td><input type="submit" class="btn" name="Submit3" value="Sign Me Up!" style="float:right" />
                                              <input type="reset" class="btn" name="Submit3" value="Reset" style="float:left" /></td>

                                          </tr>
                                          </table></td>
```

Comment: Please don't just post your code and expect us to fix it for you.

Comment: Exclude the `isset($post[number2])` from the statement and check if it's set before you try to use it. Example: `if(isset($post[number2])) $anyVar = $post[number2];`

Comment: Could you please post your HTML code also ?

Comment: Rahul, I have now posted the HTML code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix!

All I had to do was add....

```
&& $_POST['name2'] !=""|| (after each entry that may have a blank parameter.) 


//Do my PHP code
```

happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fields from your condition that you have written below **// validation expected data exists** Only put those fields in this which are really required for you and you dont want user to left it blank remove others. 
Hope this help :)

Comment: removing optional fields from the validation block did not work...I appreciate your prompt reply though...

Answer (score 0):

Remove all "optional" fields from your validation block.

Like if $_POST['number2'] is optional, exclude it.

Comment: removing optional fields from the validation block did not work...I also appreciate your reply...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the code

```
!isset($_POST['name2']) ||
```

and modify your code where you written

```
$name2 = $_POST['name2'];
```

with

```
$name2 = isset($_POST['name2'];
```

now your variable `$name2` is set. Still it may remain empty as you have left it as optional, so if you do not want to send empty values, check it before your next use `$name2` just like

```
if (!empty($name2)) {
  $email_message .= "BSB Number: ".clean_string($name2)."\n";
}
```

Still if you want keep sending empty values, like `BSB Number:    .` you can skip `if (!empty($name2))` condition.

Do this for all those optional fields you want to check with `isset()`

---

Try all this code in single file `index.php`.

```
<?php

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $email_subject = "Register Request";

    $error = false;
  $success = false;

    if (isset($_POST['Submit3'])) {

        $error_header = "<p>We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.</p>\n";
        $error_header .= "<p>These errors appear below.</p>\n";
        $error_header .= "<ul>\n";
        $error_footer = "</ul>\n";
        $error_footer .= "<p>Please go back and fix these errors.</p>\n";

    // validation expected data exists
        $error_validate = '';
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
            //!isset($_POST['name2']) ||
            !isset($_POST['number']) ||
            !isset($_POST['number2']) ||
            !isset($_POST['alternate']) ||
            !isset($_POST['accnum']) ||
            !isset($_POST['accnam']) ||
            !isset($_POST['cardnum']) ||
            !isset($_POST['expdate']) ||
            !isset($_POST['service1']) ||
            !isset($_POST['service2']) ||
            !isset($_POST['service3']) ||
            !isset($_POST['licence']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email2']) ||
            !isset($_POST['phone'])) {
                $error = true;
                $error_validate = 'We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.';
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $name2 = $_POST['name2']; 
    $number = $_POST['number']; // required
    $number2 = $_POST['number2']; 
    $alternate = $_POST['alternate']; // required
    $accnum = $_POST['accnum']; 
    $accnam = $_POST['accnam']; 
    $cardnum = $_POST['cardnum']; 
    $expdate = $_POST['expdate']; 
    $service1 = $_POST['service1']; // required
    $service2 = $_POST['service2']; // required
    $service3 = $_POST['service3']; // required
    $licence = $_POST['licence']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $email_from2 = $_POST['email2']; 
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required

    $phone = array();
        if (is_array($_POST['phone'])) {
            foreach($_POST['phone'] as $val) {
                $phone[] = (string) $val;
            }
        }
    $phone = implode(',', $phone);

    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $time = array();
        if (is_array($_POST['time'])) {
            foreach($_POST['time'] as $val) {
                $time[] = (string) $val;
            }
        }
    $time = implode(',', $time);

    $SelectedDate = $_POST['SelectedDate'];

    $error_message = "";

        if (!empty($error_validate)) {
            $error_message .= "\t<li>" . $error_validate . "</li>\n";
        }

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
            $error = true;
            $error_message .= "\t<li>The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.</li>\n";
    }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z0-9 .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
            $error = true;
            $error_message .= "\t<li>The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</li>\n";
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$number)) {
            $error = true;
            $error_message .= "\t<li>The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</li>\n";
    }

        if ($error == false) {
            function clean_string($string) {
                $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
            }

            $email_message = "Register Request\n\n";
            $email_message .= "Full Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($number)."\n";   
            $email_message .= "Date of Birth: ".clean_string($alternate)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Licence/Passport: ".clean_string($licence)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Service No.1: ".clean_string($service1)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Service No.2: ".clean_string($service2)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Service No.3: ".clean_string($service3)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Payment Option: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
            $email_message .= "BSB Number: ".clean_string($name2)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Account Number: ".clean_string($accnum)."\n"; 
            $email_message .= "Account Name: ".clean_string($number2)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Account Name: ".clean_string($accnam)."\n";
            $email_message .= "C/C Name: ".clean_string($email_from2)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Card Number: ".clean_string($cardnum)."\n";
            $email_message .= "Expiry Date: ".clean_string($expdate)."\n";

            // create email headers
            $headers = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            $success = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>E-Mail System</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: arial; }
            .status { margin: 30px auto; padding: 0 20px; }
            .error { background: #fdd; border: 1px solid #f00; }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>E-Mail System</h1>
        <?php if ($success) { ?>
            <div class="status success">
                <h2>Congratulations <?php echo $name ?>!</h2>
                <p>Your message sent successfully. We shall contact you soon.</p>
            </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php if ($error) { ?>
                <div class="status error">
                    <?php echo $error_header . $error_message . $error_footer; ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST" >
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="15%">Your Full Name</td>
                                    <td width="1%">:</td>
                                    <td width="33%"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50" required autofocus /></td>
                                    <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td width="14%">Date of Birth</td>
                                    <td width="1%">:</td>
                                    <td width="32%"><input name="alternate" type="date" id="alternate" size="20" required/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Your Address</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="number" type="text" id="number" value="" size="50" maxlength="60" required/></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>Licence/Passport No.</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="licence" type="number" id="licence" value="" size="15" maxlength="10" requried/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Email Address</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="email" type="email" id="email" size="50" required/></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><strong>Service No.1</strong></td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="service1" type="number" id="service1" value="" size="11" maxlength="10" required/></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><strong>Service No.2</strong></td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="service2" type="number" id="service2" value="" size="11" maxlength="10" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><strong>Service No.3</strong></td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="service3" type="number" id="service3" value="" size="11" maxlength="10" /></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Payment Options</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="phone[]" type="radio" value="no" id="phone_no"/><label for="checkbox">Credit Card</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="phone[]" value="yes" id="phone_yes"/><label for="checkbox">Direct Debit</label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%">BSB No.</td>
                        <td width="1%">:</td>
                        <td width="32%"><input name="name2" type="text" id="name2" size="50" /></td>
                        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td width="13%">Account Number</td>
                        <td width="1%">:</td>
                        <td width="33%"><input name="accnum" type="number" id="accnum" size="20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Account Name</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="number2" type="text" id="number2" value="" size="50" maxlength="25" /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Account in Name of</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="accnam" type="text" id="accnam" value="" size="50" maxlength="25" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name on Credit Card</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="email2" type="text" id="email2" size="50" /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Card No.</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="cardnum" type="number" id="cardnum" value="" size="50" maxlength="20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Expiry Date</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="expdate" type="number" id="expdate" value="" size="11" maxlength="4" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a class="btn" href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><a class="btn" href="termscond.html">see our Terms &amp; Conditions</a></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn" name="Submit3" value="Sign Me Up!" style="float:right" />
                            <input type="reset" class="btn" name="btnreset" value="Reset" style="float:left" />
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        <?php } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: rick Can you please confirm me the output after applying above changes. I mean is there any error or what happens?

Comment: apologies again, Ahmed this also did not work..no error returned, on sign up nothing occurred...page remained same.....

Comment: Hi @rick, I am still with you and this time I took my time to check the functionality and this time I am able to display validation messages on my pc (still I was unable to evaluate it in detail just because of time shortage, sorry for that). Anyhow, I am sending you all new code. Try it, and again tell me whatever happens. Still some  problem? no problem!